# How to convert characters dates to a date format in R?

Tags: r

I meet an issue. I can not convert my columns "date_floraison_femelle" and "date_floraison_mâle" from my dataframe. This columns are at character format but i would like to have this columns to a date format.

```
structure(list(X.2 = 1:5, PARENT_parent_verbose_name = c("lavergne_BL_2016_melange", "lavergne_BL_2016_melange", "lavergne_BL_2016_melange", "lavergne_BL_2016_melange", "lavergne_BL_2016_melange"), date_floraison_femelle = c(NA, NA, "30/08/2018", NA, "04/09/2018"), date_floraison_male = c(NA, NA, "20/08/2018", "27/08/2018", "27/08/2018"), PARENT_plante_hauteur.insertion = c(120L, 115L, 123L, 123L, 123L), PARENT_plante_hauteur = c(245L, 268L, 272L, 272L, 272L), PARENT_plante_nombre.epis = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PARENT_epi_rangs.programmes = c(12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L), PARENT_epi_grains.par.rang = c(22L, 30L, 28L, 28L, 28L), PARENT_epi_longueur = c(133L, 150L, 178L, 178L, 178L),PARENT_epi_longueur.remplie = c(112L, 141L, 151L, 151L, 151L), PARENT_epi_diametre.base = c(37L, 47L, 39L, 39L, 39L), PARENT_epi_diametre.pointe = c(31L, 35L, 38L, 38L, 38L), PARENT_epi_poids = c(69L, 113L, 120L, 120L, 120L), PARENT_epi_poids.grains = c(55L, 97L, 100L, 100L, 100L), PARENT_epi_poids.100.grains = c(19L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 28L), PARENT_epi_poids.grains.15 = c("52.118", "92.3634", "95.45", "95.45", "95.45"), PARENT_epi_poids.100.grains.15 = c("18.0044", "27.6138", "26.726", "26.726", "26.726"), ASI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm still a debutant, and I imagine that this is simple but could you help me?

Comment: df$date_floraison_femelle <- as.Date(df$date_floraison_femelle, format = "%d/%m/%Y"); 

df$date_floraison_male <- as.Date(df$date_floraison_male, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

Comment: Too good, thanks you so much have a good day mister

Answer (score 1):

We may do this in `base R`

```
nm1 <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "date_")]
df[nm1] <- lapply(df[nm1], as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

-output

```
df
  X.2 PARENT_parent_verbose_name date_floraison_femelle date_floraison_male PARENT_plante_hauteur.insertion PARENT_plante_hauteur
1   1   lavergne_BL_2016_melange                   <NA>                <NA>                             120                   245
2   2   lavergne_BL_2016_melange                   <NA>                <NA>                             115                   268
3   3   lavergne_BL_2016_melange             2018-08-30          2018-08-20                             123                   272
4   4   lavergne_BL_2016_melange                   <NA>          2018-08-27                             123                   272
5   5   lavergne_BL_2016_melange             2018-09-04          2018-08-27                             123                   272
  PARENT_plante_nombre.epis PARENT_epi_rangs.programmes PARENT_epi_grains.par.rang PARENT_epi_longueur PARENT_epi_longueur.remplie
1                         1                          12                         22                 133                         112
2                         1                          12                         30                 150                         141
3                         1                          14                         28                 178                         151
4                         1                          14                         28                 178                         151
5                         1                          14                         28                 178                         151
  PARENT_epi_diametre.base PARENT_epi_diametre.pointe PARENT_epi_poids PARENT_epi_poids.grains PARENT_epi_poids.100.grains
1                       37                         31               69                      55                          19
2                       47                         35              113                      97                          29
3                       39                         38              120                     100                          28
4                       39                         38              120                     100                          28
5                       39                         38              120                     100                          28
  PARENT_epi_poids.grains.15 PARENT_epi_poids.100.grains.15 ASI
1                     52.118                        18.0044   0
2                    92.3634                        27.6138   0
3                      95.45                         26.726   0
4                      95.45                         26.726   0
5                      95.45                         26.726   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` you can use `across` adn `dmy` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(date_floraison_femelle, date_floraison_male), dmy))
```